# unknown wsgi error when hosting django application

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Okay, so I am trying to deploy my django application on an ubuntu 16.04 sever woth apache2 and I am getting an odd error message I can't quite figure out.  I have searched around and it seems that the general answer is that I am not using the correct version of libapache2-mod-wsgi for the python version I have.  But I am using python version 2.7 and I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling libapache2-mod-wsgi and I am still getting the same error:

```
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:41.224308 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9893:tid 139847792637824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:41.224330 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9893:tid 139847792637824] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.324952 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296] [remote 129.22.1.13:58841] mod_wsgi (pid=9896): Target WSGI script '/var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/ProvCaRe/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.324997 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296] [remote 129.22.1.13:58841] mod_wsgi (pid=9896): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/ProvCaRe/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.325086 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.325098 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296]   File "/var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/ProvCaRe/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.325114 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.325124 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296]   File "/var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/prov_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.325137 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296]     from __future__ import unicode_literals
[Thu Jan 26 12:32:48.325152 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9896:tid 139847654807296] ImportError: No module named __future__
```

my apache conf file is structured:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias /static /var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/static
                <Directory /var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/static>
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>

                <Directory /var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/ProvCaRe>
                        <Files wsgi.py>
                                Require all granted
                        </Files>
                </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess ProvCaRe python-home=/var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/prov_env python-path=/var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe
        WSGIProcessGroup ProvCaRe
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html/ProvCaRe/ProvCaRe/wsgi.py


        ServerAdmin jdv12@case.edu
        ServerName provcare.case.edu
        ServerAlias www.provcare.case.edu
        DocumentRoot /var/www/provcare.case.edu/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

I'm pretty stumped so any help is appreciated

Comment: Something is wrong with your python installation. Python 2.7 should have a `__future__` module. How did you install python? Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: yes I am using a virtualenv and I just installed python using sudo apt-get install python-dev.  When I run python -V i get Python 2.7.12

Comment: Activate the virtualenv and try this command `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` to see where your python tries to import from. The file that is missing here would usually be in the location `/usr/lib/python2.7/__future__.py`

Comment: This is a module from the standard library, so it should be available just like other standard modules. https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html

Comment: When I run that command I get ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/jdv12/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

Comment: The virtualenv path is missing from that list... But the one that is important here is `/usr/lib/python2.7`. I don't know what exactly is wrong, and I don't use mod_wsgi, since I find Apache to be super confusing compared to nginx. You might find some clues in the mod_wsgi user manual. In particular the part about Virtual Environments. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html